# Remembering data with a HTTP-based API

Tags: java, api, http, cookies

I am currently developing a HTTP-based API to use my webapp through Android/Iphone/... applications.

But now I am facing a problem, let's imagine that an user is logged, should I send him a cookie with his session id in or should I do it another way ?
Making the user's device sending credentials every time it have to make a request is dirty and low (I need to access the DB), but will iOS, Android and maybe other platforms support (without any hack) cookies within a hand-crafted app (I mean not a web-browser) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies shouldn't be a problem with most HTTP Client APIs and that is pretty much the standard way to do this. You could also transfer some kind of token in another way (e.g. custom HTTP header), but why not use a standard mechanism like cookies?